# How to put compiled_sql into manifest file with dbt-core python library

Tags: dbt

I’m working with python dbt-core library to get dependency DAG, and compiled SQL code.

I managed to retrieve networkx graph with this tutorial: https://medium.com/@timleonardDS/who-lets-the-dags-out-getting-the-dag-out-of-dbt-chapter-2-d29d71620fe6. However I can’t find a way to get the compiled SQL code. I found that it was introduced a while ago here: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/829.

My question is: How to get `compiled_sql` into manifest file or how to get access to compiled SQL in the python code?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the compiled sql in the target folder:

- The `target/compiled/` directory for compiled select statements
- The `target/run/` directory for compiled create statements

Source: https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/Runs/checking-logs

You could implement a step, where you update your manifest with a custom field (which of course would have to be re-written with every manifest run).